# Install MIUI PlayStore using Google Installer, got error: can't downgrade apps for google play service

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services, miui, downgrade

In my old Xiaomi device, Mi Note2, Mi Mix2, to install google play store, I just run the google installer. It will install everything needed automatically. However recently, I tried to run Google installer on Mi 10, in the step of installing google play service, it's blocked with the following error message: "**can't downgrade apps**", seems a later version of google play service is already pre-installed. How can I bypass this error?

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for a while, I finally successfully installed Google play store. The solution is very simple. We don't need Google installer anymore as Google play service is already installed in the later MIUI version (In my case is MIUI 11), we can directly install Google play store from the APK downloaded from APK websites such as apkmirror.com. After Google play store is installed.